# HTML and CSS align divs between a line

Tags: css, html

I'm struggle to create a html design like the image bellow:
http://s8.postimage.org/abmqqm1l1/Untitled.png

I've tried something like this:

```
 <div style="display:table-cell; width:100px;"></div><img src="" width="50px";/>
 <div style="display:table-cell; margin-left:151px; width:100px;"></div><img src="" width="50px";/>
 <div style="display:table-cell; margin-left:230px; width:100px;"></div>
```

I cannot figure it out how could i do it... please help

Comment: Interesting. I think absolute positioning is your only option. I'll try to do something and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in your reference the vertical position of the boxes may overlaps. If that isn't a requirement, I would recommend using 1 unsorted list element () and assign to the list items the class "left" or "right" with appropriate "floats" . If vertical overlapping is a necessity, than I would use 2 unsorted lists with the style as follows

```
<ul class="left">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="right">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

and the style would be:

```
ul {
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;  
}
.left {
  float:left;
}
.right {
 float:right;
 padding-left:50px;
 border-left:1px solid black;
}
li {
 padding:10px 20px;
 border:1px solid black;
 width:100px;
 margin:5px;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
}
li:after {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 width:50px;
 height:1px;
 background:black;
 top:50%;
}

.left li:after {
 left:100%;
}
.right li:after {
 right:100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer . Have a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/cZ6F7/14/ ... you were pretty close !

Comment: just contain the list in a container with a fixed width and you'll be ok. (for my example, try using a container with 400px width)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `table`: [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NXCqV/2/).

Although it may appear confusing at first, once you try it out it will be pretty simple to add new branches. And it removes much of the complexity of using absolute positioning.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="border-right: 3px solid black;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="border-top: 3px solid black; border-left: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 3px solid black; border-right: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black; border-right: 3px solid black;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black; border-left: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black; border-right: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="border-right: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 3px solid black; border-left: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 3px solid black; border-left: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td style="border-top: 3px solid black; border-right: 3px solid black;"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="border-right: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black; border-left: 3px solid black;"></td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black; border-right: 3px solid black;"></td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want positioned elements more freely create container with position property and then positioned divs by top, left, bottom, right properties inside it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must draw the lines in a photo design program like paint and put the lines image in the document and position it.then by adding a `position:absolute;` and `top:value; left:value;` for each div and changing top and left values you can position each div in its true position.

for example:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; width:100px; position:absolute; top:100px; left:200px;">
```

Comment: hell no ,i have an unknown number of divs , i mean dynamic number! PLease delete this answear !

Answer (score 0):

look if that please you , just replace the imgaes by your images location

```
     [http://jsfiddle.net/ZMzyZ/]
```

your solution is with `position:absolute;`

Comment: have you tested before posting here ?