# Can I create a HTML design like this?

Tags: html, css

Can I create a HTML design like in this solution here:
[HTML and CSS align divs between a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613932/html-and-css-align-divs-between-a-lineattached)

But without using a position attribute. I'm using a table but I'm not able to design the inner DIV.
Please advise.
[image: attached image]

Comment: u mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt2yqz4t/) ?

Comment: Yes, but I have to use inline CSS cause I already declared table,ts,td with some other CSS style for other use in same page.

Comment: " have to use inline CSS ". No you don't. One CSS rule can override another even within a CSS file. But if you need to style two tables differently within a page, then the obvious solution is to use classes rather than styling the HTML tags directly.

Comment: can this is possible without using -ve margin attributes, cause Gmail does not allow negative CSS margin values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  background: #2A3F50;
  margin: 40px 0px;
}

table tr td {
  padding: 10px;
}

table tr td div {
  background: #1BBC9D;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <h3>Do you know?</h3>
        <p>Over the past 12 weeks, most product sales for <b>Combisunate 20/120 Tablets 2</b> was on <b>Weednesday Jul 12, 2017</b>b>
        </p>
        <p>
          On that day, most verification came between <b>9AM</b> and <b>10AM UTC</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/zhoolego/material/512/Folder-Doc-icon.png" width="100px" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can this is possible without using -ve margin attributes, cause Gmail does not allow negative CSS margin values.